# Display table when clicked on tree-node with data

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, quasar

So im writing an vue component that should first render a tree with following hierachy: years exapands to months expands to documentnumber from the corresponding month. This works perfectly fine. Now what I want to do is instead of displaying the documentnumber in the tree as the lowest layer of the hierachy, I want the corresponding  Document numbers, ids and dates as the table columns to render in a table when the month is clicked to display more info and to make it more user friendly. So the problem is that i cant seem to make the month node clickable to render the table on that action and displaying the doucment info. Am i missing something really stupid? Thanks in advance.

Here's the Component:

```
<template>
<q-page class="q-pa-md column items-start">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <q-input ref="filterRef" filled v-model="filter" label="Filter">
      <template v-slot:append>
        <q-icon
          v-if="filter !== ''"
          name="clear"
          class="cursor-pointer"
          @click="resetFilter"
        />
      </template>
    </q-input>
    <q-tree ref="tree" :nodes="filteredDataTree" node-key="id" no-connectors>
      <template v-slot:default="{ node, open }">
        <div class="q-pl-sm">
          <div
            v-if="node.clickable && !open"
            class="cursor-pointer"
            @click="handleNodeClick(node)"
          >
            <q-icon name="keyboard_arrow_right" />
            {{ node.label }}
          </div>
          <div v-else>
            {{ node.label }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </q-tree>
  </div>
  <div class="col" v-if="selectedMonthData.length > 0">
    <q-table
      :rows="selectedMonthData"
      :columns="tableColumns"
      row-key="id"
      flat
      dense
    >
      <template v-slot:top-right>
        <q-btn
          color="primary"
          label="Export"
          class="q-ma-md"
          @click="exportTable"
        />
      </template>
    </q-table>
  </div>
</div>
</q-page>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, computed } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "FormsPage",
  setup() {
    const filter = ref("");
    const dataTree = ref([]);

    const buildDataTree = function (documents) {
      const dataTree = [];
      const years = new Set();

      documents.forEach((doc) => {
        years.add(doc.date.getFullYear());
      });

      years.forEach((year) => {
        const yearNode = {
          id: `year-${year}`,
          label: year.toString(),
          children: [],
        };

        const months = new Set();

        documents.forEach((doc) => {
          if (doc.date.getFullYear() === year) {
            months.add(doc.date.getMonth());
          }
        });

        months.forEach((month) => {
          const monthNode = {
            id: `month-${year}-${month}`,
            label: getMonthLabel(month),
            children: [],
            clickable: true,
          };

          documents.forEach((doc) => {
            if (
              doc.date.getFullYear() === year &&
              doc.date.getMonth() === month
            ) {
              const docNode = {
                id: doc.id,
                label: doc.name,
                data: doc,
              };
              monthNode.children.push(docNode);
            }
          });

          yearNode.children.push(monthNode);
        });

        dataTree.push(yearNode);
      });

      return dataTree;
    };

    const resetFilter = function () {
      filter.value = "";
    };

    const formatDate = function (date) {
      const options = { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" };
      return date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options);
    };

    const filteredDataTree = computed(() => {
      if (filter.value === "") {
        return dataTree.value;
      } else {
        const selectedYear = parseInt(filter.value);
        if (!isNaN(selectedYear)) {
          return dataTree.value
            .map((yearNode) => {
              const filteredMonths = yearNode.children.filter((monthNode) => {
                return monthNode.label === selectedYear.toString();
              });
              if (filteredMonths.length > 0) {
                return { ...yearNode, children: filteredMonths };
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            })
            .filter((node) => node !== null);
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      }
    });

    const getMonthLabel = function (month) {
      const monthNames = [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December",
      ];
      return monthNames[month];
    };

    const selectedMonthData = ref([]);
    const tableColumns = [
      {
        name: "Document Number",
        required: true,
        label: "Document Number",
        align: "left",
        field: "nr",
        sortable: true,
      },
      {
        name: "ID",
        required: true,
        label: "ID",
        align: "left",
        field: "id",
        sortable: true,
      },
      {
        name: "date",
        required: true,
        label: "date",
        align: "left",
        field: "date",
        sortable: true,
        format: (value) => formatDate(value),
      },
    ];

    const handleNodeClick = (node) => {
      if (node.clickable) {
        selectedMonthData.value = [];
      }
    };


    const loadData = function () {
      this.$q.loading.show({
        delay: 50, // ms
      });
      this.$api
        .get("/foo/bar")
        .then((response) => {
          const convertedData = response.data.map((doc) => ({
            ...doc,
            date: parseDate(doc.date),
          }));

          dataTree.value = buildDataTree(convertedData);
          this.$q.loading.hide();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          this.$q.loading.hide();
          this.$q.notify({
            color: "negative",
            position: "top",
            message: "Loading failed",
            icon: "report_problem",
          });
        });
    };

    const parseDate = function (date) {
      const year = Math.floor(date / 10000);
      const month = Math.floor((date % 10000) / 100) - 1;
      const day = date % 100;
      return new Date(year, month, day);
    };

    return {
      filter,
      filteredDataTree,
      resetFilter,
      formatDate,
      selectedMonthData,
      tableColumns,
      handleNodeClick,
      loadData
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadData();
  }
});
</script>
```

I've tried to remove the "lowest" layer of the tree and tried to modify the "handleNodeClick" so the table from the template gets rendered.